# Binding issues: extending a class leads method calling itself?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have another question related to bindings ([Issues with Bindings: Calling base method on binding class calls override method. Leads to infinite recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693762/issues-with-bindings-calling-base-method-on-binding-class-calls-override-method)), and it has become unwieldy long, so I figure I would start over with a new question that encompasses the best information I know at this point.

I am trying to use Cordova in a project I'm working on within MonoTouch. I've been working on a binding for Cordova.

Here is my binding for the Cordova 2.4.0 classes (available here https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/tree/2.4.0/CordovaLib/Classes): (*Note this is not a complete binding, just the pieces I need so far*)

```
interface CDVScreenOrientationDelegate {
    [Export ("supportedInterfaceOrientations")]
    uint SupportedInterfaceOrientations ();

    [Export ("shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:")]
    bool ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation);

    [Export ("shouldAutorotate")]
    bool ShouldAutoRotate ();
}

[BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
interface CDVViewController : CDVScreenOrientationDelegate {
    [Export ("webView")]
    UIWebView WebView { get; set; }

    [Export ("pluginObjects")]
    NSMutableDictionary PluginObjects { get; }

    [Export ("pluginsMap")]
    NSDictionary PluginsMap { get; }

    [Export ("settings")]
    NSDictionary Settings { get; }

    [Export ("whitelist")]
    CDVWhitelist Whitelist { get; }

    [Export ("loadFromString")]
    bool LoadFromString { get; }

    [Export ("useSplashScreen")]
    bool UseSplashScreen { get; set; }

    [Export ("activityView")]
    UIActivityIndicatorView ActivityView { get; }

    [Export ("imageView")]
    UIImageView ImageView { get; }

    [Export ("wwwFolderName")]
    string WwwFolderName { get; set; }

    [Export ("startPage")]
    string StartPage { get; set; }

    [Export ("commandQueue")]
    NSObject CommandQueue { get; set; }

    [Export ("commandDelegate")]
    NSObject CommandDelegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("userAgent")]
    string UserAgent { get; }

    [Export ("printMultitaskingInfo")]
    void PrintMultitaskingInfo ();

    [Export ("createGapView")]
    void CreateGapView ();

    [Export ("newCordovaViewWithFrame:")]
    UIWebView NewCordovaView(RectangleF bounds);

    [Export ("javascriptAlert:")]
    void JavascriptAlert (string text);

    [Export ("appURLScheme")]
    string AppUrlScheme ();

    [Export ("parseInterfaceOrientations:")]
    NSArray ParseInterfaceOrientations (NSArray orientations);

    [Export ("supportsOrientation:")]
    bool SupportsOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation orientation);

    [Export ("getCommandInstance:")]
    NSObject GetCommandInstance (string pluginName);

    [Export ("registerPlugin:withClassName:")]
    void RegisterPluginWithClassName (CDVPlugin plugin, string className);

    [Export ("URLisAllowed:")]
    bool UrlIsAllowed (NSUrl url);

    [Static] [Export ("getBundlePlist:")]
    NSDictionary GetBundlePlist (string plistName);

    [Static] [Export ("applicationDocumentsDirectory")]
    string ApplicationDocumentsDirectory ();

    // The following methods and properties come from UIWebViewDelegate, but we can't do multiple inheritance
    //[Export ("webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:")]
    //bool ShouldStartLoad (UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType);
}

[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface CDVWhitelist {
    [Export ("whitelist")]
    NSArray Whitelist { get; }

    [Export ("expandedWhitelist")]
    NSArray ExpandedWhitelist { get; }

    [Export ("allowAll")]
    bool AllowAll { get; }

    [Export ("initWithArray:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (NSArray array);

    [Export ("URLIsAllowed:")]
    bool UrlIsAllowed (NSUrl url);

    [Export ("schemeIsAllowed:")]
    bool SchemeIsAllowed (string scheme);

    [Export ("errorStringForURL:")]
    string ErrorStringForUrl (NSUrl url);
}

[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface CDVPlugin {
    [Export ("webView")]
    UIWebView WebView { get; set; }

    [Export ("viewController")]
    UIViewController ViewController { get; set; }

    [Export ("commandDelegate")]
    NSObject CommandDelegate { get; set; }

    [Export ("hasPendingOperation")]
    bool HasPendingOperation { get; }

    [Export ("initWithWebView:")]
    CDVPlugin InitWithWebView (UIWebView theWebView);

    [Export ("handleOpenURL:")]
    void HandleOpenUrl (NSNotification notification);

    [Export ("onAppTerminate")]
    void OnAppTerminate ();

    [Export ("onMemoryWarning")]
    void OnMemoryWarning ();

    [Export ("onReset")]
    void OnReset ();

    [Export ("appDelegate")]
    NSObject AppDelegate ();
}
```

This is using the protocol of miguel.de.icaza from [Monotouch Binding Syntax For Protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477037/monotouch-binding-syntax-for-protocols). This doesn't have the UIWebViewDelegate that is is also adopted by CDVViewController

```
@interface CDVViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, CDVScreenOrientationDelegate>{
    @protected
    CDVCommandDelegateImpl* _commandDelegate;
    @protected
    CDVCommandQueue* _commandQueue; 
    NSString* _userAgent;
}
```

Alternatively, I found Rolf Bjarne Kvinge recommend the Adopts syntax at http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Objective-C-protocol-binding-method-not-invoked-td4105828.html. Unfortunately, I couldn't get this working, as when I would attempt to build my binding, it would complain about not being able to conform `System.Type` to `String`. That is a different issue though.

When I attempt to subclass CDVViewController, I run into other issues. Specifically After ViewDidLoad is called, the system calls my subclasses' `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

To confirm this, I did the following:

```
public class WebViewController : CDVViewController
{
    public override bool ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Enter ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation");
        var output = base.ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation;
        Console.WriteLine ("Leave ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation");
        return output;
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint inside the `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, and as I step along the method, when I get to the `base.ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, it just hops back to the beginning of this method, and my call stack has now added `Cordova.CDVViewController.ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, but looking at the source code for this method (available [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/2.4.0/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVViewController.m#L370)), it never attempts to call itself, or a subclass implementation. Instead it calls `supportsOrientation:` internally, which checks an array to see if this orientation is supported.

Knowing that `supportsOrientation:` is called in the end anyway, I tried calling it from `ShouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` as well, but then I just get the weird calling itself back behaviour in that method instead.

If I instantiate `CDVViewController` directly, then everything seems to work as expected, but I need to override some methods for my project. When I extend `CDVViewController`,
then this behaviour starts happening.

I'm quite confused by this, and I can't figure what what I am doing wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update #1** Based on Rolf's request, here are the generated classes. I hope this is what you were looking for. For space reasons, I am adding it as a Gist here https://gist.github.com/innopal/5288047

Comment: Can you find the generated code for the binding and see/post what it looks like? If you right-click the solution and chose to view all files, the generated files are in a subdirectory somewhere (can't remember the name exactly, but it shouldn't take you long to find it).

Comment: Thanks for the response Rolf. I found these in the DLL I generated. I hope that helps https://gist.github.com/innopal/5288047

Comment: are you using a binding project or are using btouch manually?

Comment: I'm using btouch manually, using the following command `/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch -e Cordova.cs -s Enums.cs AssemblyInfo.cs --out:Cordova.dll --link-with=libcordova.a,libCordova.a`. Would you recommend a binding project instead? I used https://github.com/sblom/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/Cordova/Binding as a starting point to figure out how to bind things.

Comment: Try removing the "-e" argument.

Comment: And there we have it. `-e  Generates smaller classes that can not be subclassed`. That solves it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem, as pointed out by Rolf was that I was including the `-e` flag in my arguments.

As noted in the help for `btouch`,

```
-e  Generates smaller classes that cannot be subclassed (previously called 'external mode').
```

So the problem here was I was unknowingly using a flag that specifically makes the classes unsubclassable, and then trying to subclass them.